# Retrieve value from the document in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, bson

[image]

**Query:** when i give "third_party_site_id" value in the above script in result i want only st_site_id value ?
How to write the script to get only st_site_id value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.collection.find({'third_party_site_id.fieldName':'valueToCheck'}, {st_site_id:`1})

First part is find query.
Second part is projection.

I suggest you to refer documentation